# how I start activity which is caller and close activty which is callling at same time?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity

I want to call a activty but when I call actviy I want to finish my caller activty , How can I do this?

```
  A:caller
  B:calling

 startActivity(new Intent(A.this, B.class));
  finish();
```

I write this code but everything is closing.

Comment: Show code of Activity A and B

Comment: this way you can finish the activity. paste your full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

> This launch mode can also be used to good effect in conjunction with
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK: if used to start the root activity of a task,
>   it will bring any currently running instance of that task to the
>   foreground, and then clear it to its root state. This is especially
>   useful, for example, when launching an activity from the notification
>   manager.

Comment: thanks for answering but when I write this code , my class dont finish.I want to finish my caller activty

Comment: In my practice you just should call finish() method from your caller. I dont know, why your code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this:

```
              startActivity(new Intent(A.this, B.class));
              A.this.finish();
```

Comment: Its perfectly working.Activity A will be removed from the activity stack.